# Call to undefined function sem_get() for implemeting queue in PHP

Tags: php, linux, centos, semaphore

I want to implement queues in PHP using FIFO. For this, I have installed Semophore.

[image]

**But I am getting the error "Call to undefined function sem_get()"**

It seems like it is showing in phpinfo, but still giving error

Any help?

Comment: Are you running the queue on the command line? That can have an entirely different installation or configuration of PHP. Do `php -i` on the command line to check its installed modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to work but I have implemented a queue using Redis in PHP

```
$redis = new Redis(); 
$redis->connect('127.0.0.1', 6379); 
//set the data in redis string 
$redis->set("quenename", "enter queue name");    
   
//Getting data in redis string   
$redis→get("quenename");
```

#Further, the code has been updated using redis library

```
$redis = $this->redis();
$ret = $redis->connect(REDIS_HOST, ZGH_REDIS_PORT);
$res = $redis->lPush(REDIS_HRGAME_PUSH_BATCH_KEY,$pushInfo);
```

#I am not adding the whole code. This is just for the solution if someone also trying to implement same in PHP.

Comment: You probably don't want `$redis->set` for queuing. You'd probably want something like `LPUSH`. https://redis.io/commands/lpush/

Comment: Yes, I have already change code to that